# Can't connect to remote server through ssh (after nx server install)

Tags: linux, ssh

I can't connect to remote server through ssh using public key auth. I was trying NX server. I removed it. And now then if I trying to connect I'm getting:

```
ssh user@server -p 2222 
bash: /usr/NX/bin/nxnode: No such file or directory Connection to server closed.
```

How to remove this "nxnode" ssh wrapper and fix ssh connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get access to the server, e.g. via some rescue system if ssh connections don't work anymore.

I don't really know what NXserver does to your sshd configuration, but it looks like it either changes the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or the `authorized_keys` file on the server so that `/usr/NX/bin/nxnode` is called. Login to the server somehow and check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (or `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the root user) for any directives containing `/usr/NX/bin/nxnode`.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I had connection today and I checked /etc/sshd_config. But haven't found anything. After I will have connection to console I will check /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys. I just thinking maybe NX changing /etc/passwd file ? Is it worth to check ? I don't have access to server now. Just asking because someone may have straight answer. Thanks. I will check these files.

Comment: You can also check /etc/passwd, but I don't think the login shell for the user has been changed there, because the error message says `bash:...`

Comment: Line /usr/NX/bin/nxnode contained in .ssh/authorized_keys file. Thanks